# Universal macOS app won't build due to sqlite3 dylib being arm only

Tags: macos, sqlite, linker

I am building a universal macOS app which uses sqlite3.
The library that comes with the system is of course architecture specific.
So when archiving, XCode ignores the system library and emits linker errors because there is not an intel version.

So will I have to download and embed a multi-architecture version of the library?
Or is there a weak link flag I can use?

Also the compiler emits a warning about sqlite version built for newer OS version (13) than being linked (deployment target macOS 12).

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about noise. Discovered I could embed the sqlite3 source directly into my project.
Downloaded amalgamation source file and it just worked (with some minor warnings about int sizes).